# Is there a way I can make buttons in Tkinter with a for loop, while also giving each one a different command?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a revision system for school, and I want it to be able to use a modular amount of subjects just in case a subject is added to the system, so I need a way to make a number of buttons with different subject names, and be able to differentiate between those buttons using tkinter. So for example, if they were to click the Mathematics button, it would take them to another bit of code specially suited for mathematics(Although, it can't be solely for Mathematics, since then I would need definitions for subjects that haven't even been added yet)

First I simply tried setting the command to "print(subjectnames[subcount-1])", thinking it would print the name of the button, but that just printed both names out straight away without even pressing a button. Then I tried changing the variable name subject to the name of the button, which I didn't expect to work, I was just stumped and desperate

Here I started setting up the definition

```py
def chooseQuiz():
    clearWindow()
    subjectnames=[]
    button=[]
```

This was probably unimportant, just labels for the title and spacing

```py
    Label(mainWindow, text="Which quizzes would you like to take?", bg='purple3', font=('constantia',25,"bold")).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=100, pady=0)
    Label(mainWindow, bg='purple3').grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=15)
```

Here I extract data from an SQL table to get all subject names from all topics, again probably unimportant but here is where most of the variables are made

```py
    c.execute("SELECT Subject_name FROM topics")
    for row in c.fetchall():
        if row[0] in subjectnames:
            pass
        elif row[0] not in subjectnames:
            subjectnames.append(row[0])
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "subjectnames are not appending")
            chooseQuiz()
```

This is the main part of this question, where I tried to form a fluid number of buttons all with different commands, but to no avail

```py
    for subcount in range(len(subjectnames)):
        button.append(Button(mainWindow, text=str(subjectnames[subcount-1]), bg='grey', fg='black', font=('cambria',15), width=25, command=(subject==subjectnames[subcount-1])))
        button[-1].grid(row=subcount+2,column=0, padx=0, pady=15)
```

I expected the subject variable to be the same as the button I pressed, but it remained at 0(original value). I think this is due to wrong use of the command function in tkinter on my part. The buttons still showed up fine(only 2 subjects currently, Mathematics and Physics, and both showed up fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The following example creates a window with a reset button; upon clicking reset, a frame is populated with buttons corresponding to a random number of buttons chosen randomly from possible subjects. Each button has a command that calls a `display` function that redirects the call to the proper topic, which, in turn prints the name of its topic to the console, for simplicity of the example. You could easily create functions/classes corresponding to each topic, to encapsulate more sophisticated behavior.

Adding subjects, is as simple as adding a `key-value` pair in `SUBJECTS`

Pressing `reset` again, removes the current button and replaces them with a new set chosen randomly.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from _tkinter import TclError


SUBJECTS = {'Maths': lambda:print('Maths'), 
            'Physics': lambda:print('Physics'),
            'Chemistry': lambda:print('Chemistry'),
            'Biology': lambda:print('Biology'),
            'Astronomy': lambda:print('Astronomy'),
            'Petrology': lambda:print('Petrology'),}

topics = []


def topic_not_implemented():
    print('this topic does not exist')


def get_topics():
    """randomly creates a list of topics for this example
    """
    global topics
    topics = []
    for _ in range(random.randrange(1, len(SUBJECTS))):
        topics.append(random.choice(list(SUBJECTS.keys())))
    return topics


def reset_topics():
    global topics_frame

    try:
        for widget in topics_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        topics_frame.forget()
        topics_frame.destroy()
    except UnboundLocalError:
        print('error')
    finally:
        topics_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        topics_frame.pack()
    for topic in get_topics():
        tk.Button(topics_frame, text=topic, command=lambda topic=topic: display(topic)).pack()


def display(topic):
    """redirects the call to the proper topic
    """
    SUBJECTS.get(topic, topic_not_implemented)()


root = tk.Tk()
reset = tk.Button(root, text='reset', command=reset_topics)
reset.pack()
topics_frame = tk.Frame(root)
topics_frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't need it to send it to multiple different functions or classes, just one that would then show all topics in the SQL database with that subject name in them, since I want it to be able to accept subjects that I might not have added when I'm finished. Would I be able to change, for example, a variable called current subject to the name of the current button?

Comment: Your question was: "Is there a way I can make buttons in Tkinter with a for loop, while also giving each one a different command?", which is what my response answers. Of course, it would be possible to change variables values, dynamically add or remove subjects, and other things too, but that would be a different question. If my answer helped you, you should accept it. If you have other problems, you can post a new question.